# Why use the existing radio tower?

Tags: fallout-4

At a certain point in the Minute Men quests you obtain a settlement which has a large radio in it. This radio requires 10 power and a settler to use it.

Compared to the default radio (1 power, no settler) it has some major drawbacks. **Is there any reason to continue using that radio?** (other than to listen to the station is creates)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The radio tower you're talking about at the Castle is a long range broadcast tower for coordinating Minuteman activities across the Commonwealth, such as artillery strikes and notification of regions that need assistance.

You do not need the long range tower to continue the Minutemen quests.

The small broadcast tower you can build in your settlements is much smaller range and used for recruiting new settlers.

Comment: I think you also need the tower to get more Minuteman quests.

Comment: I can confirm that is not the case, I added that information to @Kalina's answer

Comment: Note that if you want more settlers to show up at The Castle I'm pretty sure you'll need a small recruitment tower as well.